# Evolution of Anoles

Tags: evolution, homework, ecology

For context, I am currently looking at this virtual lab of Lizard Evolution by HHMI biointeractive.

Trunk anoles from an island called Iron Cay were placed in a few experimental islands filled with small bushes and grass.Over four years, the researchers measured the length of the hindlimbs of the anoles. After four years, they found that the average hindlimb length of the anoles in the experimental islands was shorter than that of those on Iron Cay.

I was wondering if the anoles from the experimental island were brought back to Iron Cay, would the anoles still mate with each other?

Thank you!

Comment: On the face of it, this seems to be a question regarding the behaviour of artificial constructs in a computer program and not a biology one. I gather it's an educational program, but I'm not familiar how it's programmed or how it can be adjusted to behave. Perhaps you should just try it and see. If you've an actual biology question about the scenario in real life, (about speciation) then please ask it, but the question as it is now seems to me to be off-topic. Please take our [tour] and read up in the [help], noting the [ask] section.

Comment: This is also definitely a homework question... note our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on the [different mechanisms of reproductive isolation](http://abacus.gene.ucl.ac.uk/jim/Sp/isolmech.html). It's possible that changes in hindlimb length or morphology could be a source of behavioral or mechanical isolation, though post-mating barriers to reproductive compatibility would be unlikely on such short timescales

Comment: to clarify the two lizard populations have only been separated for 4 years right?  There's no reason to expect too much evolution to occur in 4 years.  If the surviving lizards have longer legs then I'd argue that all that happened is just the short legged lizards died.  While that is evolution, since the lizards are the exact same individuals taken to the island 4 years earlier, there's no reason to expect they'll have changed their mate choice behavior.